# how to install wine on exagear ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, wine

hi im having hard times installing wine on ubuntu 12.04lts in exagear guest shell does anyone know how to install it. it says something about the bindery and to check the guide someone help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install wine under exagear follow this steps:
Enter the guest Ubuntu:
$ exagear
Install wine as usual:
$ sudo apt-get install wine
If this doesn't result in succsessful installation, please put here the exact errror message.